# How to consume Restful webservice from external jar

Tags: java, spring, rest, executable-jar, resttemplate

I would like to consume the Restful API from the executable jar.
The restful APIs are deployed in Wildfly server.

Is there any possibility to consume the RestFul APIs from outside. i.e., from the executable jar?

Note: This jar won't be deployed in the server, so we can't use spring.

Comment: 1. Yes you can use Spring (AFAIK), 2. That is the actual point of a RESTful API: to be usable "from outside"... What makes you think you cannot? Here is a Spring-Guide on that: http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

Comment: Thanks Fildor. I will check the link you provided.

Comment: I don't think there is no point in giving down vote. If everyone knows everything, then this website won't be grown this much.

Comment: I did not dv but most beginners get downvoted for lack of research effort shown. But that's only a guess. Only the downvoter knows why.

Answer (score 0):

You can do just that by using **OkHttp** http://square.github.io/okhttp/